# Can't execute makefile in Windows 7

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make, mingw32, suitesparse

I'm trying to compile library https://github.com/PetterS/SuiteSparse/tree/master/CSparse
with MinGW on Windows 7.

Makefile contents:

```
C:
    ( cd Lib ; $(MAKE) )
    ( cd Demo ; $(MAKE) )

all: C cov

library:
    ( cd Lib ; $(MAKE) )

cov:
    ( cd Tcov ; $(MAKE) )

clean:
    ( cd Lib ; $(MAKE) clean )
    ( cd Demo ; $(MAKE) clean )
    ( cd Tcov ; $(MAKE) clean )
    ( cd MATLAB/CSparse ; $(RM) *.o )
    ( cd MATLAB/Test    ; $(RM) *.o )

purge:
    ( cd Lib ; $(MAKE) purge )
    ( cd Demo ; $(MAKE) purge )
    ( cd Tcov ; $(MAKE) purge )
    ( cd MATLAB/CSparse ; $(RM) *.o *.mex* )
    ( cd MATLAB/Test    ; $(RM) *.o *.mex* )

distclean: purge

# do not install CSparse; use CXSparse instead
install:

# uninstall CSparse: do nothing
uninstall:
```

I'im typing in cmd.exe:

```
PS C:\Users\s\Desktop\CSparse> mingw32-make
( cd Lib ; C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make )
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, ( cd Lib ; C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make ), ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'C' failed
mingw32-make: *** [C] Error 2
```

My Path variable:

```
C:\Program Files\PC Connectivity Solution\;C:\watcom-1.3\binnt;C:\watcom-1.3\binw;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\ia32\compiler;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\;C:\Program Files\Panda3D-1.8.1\python;C:\Program Files\Panda3D-1.8.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Backburner\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\runtime\win32;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;
```

I have rebooted Windows already.
I also tried to set path=C:\MinGW\bin in cmd.exe, but nothing have changed.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `C:\mingw32\bin` or `C:\MinGW\bin`?

Comment: Sorry. Yes, it was "C:\MinGW\bin".

Comment: So you did not copy/paste these details verbatim. I wonder what else you got wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> I also tried to set path=C:\mingw32\bin in cmd.exe, but nothing have changed.

As far I'm concerned, by typing this you make PATH variable contains **only** path "C:\mingw32\bin". 
Have look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9546345/4776786

Try this instead in CMD:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\mingw32\bin
```

By executing that command you **add** that directory to your current PATH variable.

But, in other hand, why you just don't use "My Computer" > "Properties" > "Advanced" > "Environment Variables" > "Path"?  Doing this, system reboot will not interrupt your PATH.

Comment: I have already changed PATH via "My Computer" > "Properties" > "Advanced" > "Environment Variables" > "Path" and rebooted Windows. But I still have the same problem.

Comment: Sorry to tell you you wasted all that time, but you do not need to reboot Windows.